# Filter Return of Meteor FindOne?

Tags: javascript, meteor

How would I go about filtering the return of a FindOne function in Iron Router? I assume that aggregation is out of the question, but I may be wrong. I've tried many different ways that don't work. I'd like to return the id, name, and the season object that it finds a matching season_number in.

My database is setup like so:

- _id
- name
- seasons    (array)

  - season (object)

    - season_number
    - episodes (array)

      - episode (object)

        - episode_title
        - episode_number

Here's my iron router code that is currently just running a findOne function.

```js
Router.route('/show/:_id/season/:season_number', {
  name: 'viewSeasonPage', // This links to the template
  data: function() { return Tv.findOne({_id:"KQBXq4nri7zssDna2", "seasons.season_number": 2}))}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    Router.route('/show/:_id/season/:season_number', {
      name: 'viewSeasonPage', // This links to the template
      data: function() { 
               let tv = Tv.findOne({_id:"KQBXq4nri7zssDna2", "seasons.season_number": 2});
               if (tv && tv.seasons) { return tv.seasons.find(function(season) { return season.season_number == 2; })
            }
    });
```

Comment: That still returns the full doc then.

Comment: once you have the full doc, then you can parse it and get what you need or add the {fields: } options.
Maybe if your case the projection is better suited: 
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/

Comment: I can't use projection, as Meteor pops up this error: Minimongo doesn't support $ operator in projections yet.

Comment: then you need to filter the result and get what you want... see edits

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter the result to create the data object you want to return with the information you need. If your search doesn't find anything, your data is an empty object.

```
Router.route('/show/:_id/season/:season_number', {
    name: 'viewSeasonPage',
    data: function() {
        // Find your object
        var tv = Tv.findOne({
            _id: this.params._id,
            seasons: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    season_number: this.params.season_number
                }
            }
        });
        // Fill data by filtering the correct season
        var data = {};
        if (tv) {
            data._id = tv._id;   // 1. ID
            data.name = tv.name; // 2. NAME
            // Find correct season in array
            var season;
            for (var i = tv.seasons.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                season = tv.seasons[i];
                if (season.season_number == this.params.season_number) {
                    data.season = season; // 3. SEASON
                }
            };
        }
        return data;
    }
});
```

I know it's a lot of coding, but this is for understanding the idea and the process.